# Angular How to submit event on modal component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a modal component with this template:

```
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

In the ng content I pass with a service a template like this:

```
  <form  #contactForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    /*some inputs */

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

I need to do a submit in my modal component on click on the button positioned on the footer section....I don't need the button inside the form (Must I hide it?) but I can't find a solution...How can I solve this situation?

Comment: This may help: https://medium.com/@Zeroesandones/emit-an-event-from-a-child-to-parent-component-in-angular-9-7c3690c75f6

Answer (score 2):

template

```
<form #testForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(testForm)">
  <p>
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" ngModel />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" [(ngModel)]="lastname" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>

<button (click)="save()">Submit</button>
```

ts code

```
export class HelloComponent {
  title = "Template driven forms";
  lastname = "patel";
  @ViewChild(NgForm) testForm: NgForm;
  
  onSubmit(contactForm) {
    console.log(contactForm.value);
  }
  save(e) {
    this.testForm.onSubmit(e);
  }
}
```